# Objects Spawning very quicky using Invoke Repeating in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

so I am making a game in which a list of GameObject spawn from a certain point, I created a method which is referenced in invoke repeating which is in void Start, but even after applying delay and interval the objects are spawning instantly, pls help me!!

Here's the Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] buildings;

    [SerializeField]
    private float delay=5f;

    [SerializeField]
    private float interval=10f;

    [SerializeField]
    private int destroyDis;
    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("spawnBuildings", -2000f, -5000f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        spawnBuildings();
    }

    public void spawnBuildings()
    {
        int bIndex = Random.Range(0, buildings.Length);
        Vector2 pos = transform.position;
        Instantiate(buildings[bIndex],pos,Quaternion.identity,this.transform);
    }
}
```

Here's the pic:
[image]

Comment: why do you start with negative time to start and repeat? do you have a tardis? - on top of that as pointed out in the answer section you also call it per frame...

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `spawnBuildings` once a frame in `Update`, so every frame you're making a new building. You probably want to remove it from `Update` and leave the call to `InvokeRepeating` in `Start`.

Also, your call to `InvokeRepeating`, the second and third arguments should be the initial delay and repeat rate, respectively. You have them set to `-2000f` and `-5000f`, which aren't valid time values, since they're negative. Judging from the rest of your code, it looks like you want `InvokeRepeating("spawnBuildings", delay, interval);` instead.

You can see the documentation for `InvokeRepeating` here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html

Comment: Actually i tried with a positive number but the result are same

Comment: I updated the answer! Let me know if this works

Comment: ohhhh really sorry for my dumbnesss

Comment: Thx the code is working, btw is their a way to randomize the interval delay in between 3-5 secs???

Comment: I'm not sure of a way to do that with `InvokeRepeating`, but you can definitely achieve that with some custom code in `FixedUpdate`.

Comment: If you want to randomize then don't use `InvokeRepeating` but a simple check `if(Time.time >= newTime){ newTime = Time.time + Random.Range(minDelay, maxDelay); spawnBuildings(); }`